# Put bounty when you are already bankrupt?

Tags: support, questions, bounties

This [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4857/ande-turner) has currently only 129 points. And he had placed a bounty of 550 points for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167393/vala-gotchas-tips-and-tricks). If somebody rightly answers this, from whose account does this 550 points come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once the bounty is created, the points are removed in anticipation of a future answer. The 129 rep that you see now is the result *after* bounty-rep deletion.

Comment: Yea, the -500 is reflected in the reputation tab/graph

Comment: Came across this same thing today, though oh wow, SO is giving loans.